# Multiple results in a view due to taxonomy?

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type called "Stuff". Which has a taxonomy term called "Area". There are three Areas: A, B and C. I have a view that lists the content. The problem is, I get duplicates based if a node is assigned to multiple terms.

So for example, if I have three nodes, each assigned to ONE taxonomy term, I end up with:

```
Stuff 1 | A
Stuff 2 | B
Stuff 3 | C
```

But if I assign a node to multiple terms I end up with:

```
Stuff 1 | A
Stuff 2 | B
Stuff 3 | C
Stuff 4 | A, B, C
Stuff 4 | A, B, C
Stuff 4 | A, B, C
```

I've tried:

- Going under ADVANCED --> OTHER --> QUERY SETTINGS --> DISTINCT ...

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**UPDATE**

If I use aggregation, I get:

```
Stuff 1 | A
Stuff 2 | B
Stuff 3 | C
Stuff 4 | A
Stuff 4 | B
Stuff 4 | C
```

But I want:

```
Stuff 1 | A
Stuff 2 | B
Stuff 3 | C
Stuff 4 | A, B, C
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use aggregation. It's just above query settings.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. See update in my answer and the result I get.

Comment: What about grouping? Format > Settings > Grouping Field And then try grouping by title (or whatever field "Stuff 1" is). I quickly tried this and it reduces duplicates although the formatting is a little weird so you will have to adjust that somehow

Comment: No. All I get now is the three terms below a header. I want drupal to see them as one. Which is why I do believe aggregation should be what solves this, but it doesn't. Will keep looking...